# Program that uses a For to calculate a set of values

Tags: python

How can I handle the part from while True to the for? I need an exception that tells the user that he needs to enter a number (in case he accidentally types a string) or a value > 0. I tried converting the nyear to an int so it would raise a value error but this only lead to an error.

So how would you guys handle this?

```
 def main():

    nyear = int(raw_input('Enter the years: '))    
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            intTarget = int(nyear)
        except ValueError:
            print 'Value needs to be a number and needs to be greater than 0'

        nyear = int(raw_input('Enter the years: '))

    for year in range(nyear):
        for month in range(12):
            rinch = float(raw_input('How many inches of rain: '))
            i += rinch 

        total = i
        tmonths = (month + 1) * (year + 1)
        ravg = total/tmonths
        print total, tmonths, ravg        
main()
```

Comment: You already convert it to int before even entering the try block.

Comment: Put a `break` below `intTarget = int(nyear)`.

Comment: 1. you have write `int(raw_input('Enter the years: '))` statement two times- write only once in code. 2. As you want to again `Enter the years:` again and again - so move code of this statement into `while` loop.  3. Do Type conversion ins `try and exception` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move `raw_input` statement into `try` block.
2. Use `break` keyword to break `while` loop when user enter valid number string.
3. Convert user value from `string` to `int`. if any exception raise during type conversion then ask again. This will go in exception part of code.
4. Also check enter number is greater then 0 or not by `if` loop.

Use 
e.g.

```
while True:
    try:
        nyear = int(raw_input('Enter the years: '))
        if nyear>0:
            break
        print 'Value needs to be a number and needs to be greater than 0.'
    except ValueError:
        print 'Value needs to be a number and needs to be greater than 0.'
```

Output:

```
Enter the years: w
Value needs to be a number and needs to be greater than 0.
Enter the years: -100
Value needs to be a number and needs to be greater than 0.
Enter the years: 2015
```

Comment: yes, What are your rules for year validation? 1. Must be number 2. only positive number or  any more??

Comment: updated. `year` value must be greater then `0`.